# GeoServer - How to add files in GeoServer VM

Tags: geoserver, image-mosaic

I would like to add files in GeoServer. GeoServer is not in local but in computer of my company.

How it possible to add files (using Image Mosaic).

[image]

Comment: do you have the files on the remote machine? if not you will need to copy them there using scp or sftp and then add them using the usual store mechanism

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the GeoServer REST interface to do this using a file from your machine (wsiearth2.tif).

https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/rest/api/datastores.html#workspaces-ws-datastores-ds-file-url-external-extension

For example I did the following from a Windows command line then my layer showed up in GeoServer:

```
curl --noproxy "*" -v -u admin:geoserver -XPUT -H "Content-type: image/tiff" --data-binary @wsiearth2.tif http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/mort/coveragestores/wsiearth2/file.geotiff
```